# ¿Como agregar símbolo "><" dentro de etiqueta Text en React native?

Tags: react-native, text

Quiero agregar estos simbolos "><" dentro de una etiqueta Text, en mi proyecto de React native con javascript, pero me tira un error "Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'>'}` or `&gt;`?"

Alguien sabe como agregarlo sin que lo tome como error? Anexo el código y la imagen:

<Text sx={{ ...Styles.paragraph, ...elementSizes.summaryLinkText }}>

Recuerda que tu nueva contraseña debe contener por lo menos 8 caracteres incluyendo al menos

una mayúscula, una minúscula, un número y un caracter especial como @$!%*?&^.[]{}()\/"#,><:;|_~`=+-

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba sustituyendo `><` por `&gt;&lt;`

Comment: Gracias! Si me ha funcionado

Comment: Perfecto, no se react, pero esos simbolos en HTML se representan con esas entidades ([más info](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp))